# Minimal way to render Wiki Syntax (for example MoinMoin Wiki)

Tags: javascript, wiki, moinmoin

I enjoy using to Wikis to document all kind of stuff (recently I used MoinMoin, so I am used to that syntax).

Now I am looking for a more lightweight solution, for documents where setting up a MoinMoin server is too much hassle.

What is the "easiest" way to render a .txt file in Wiki syntax (for example by displaying it, or converting it to HTML)?

It should work on Linux, but the more platform-independent, the better.

Maybe there is even a JavaScript based solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown), it's the syntax used here on stackoverflow. There's a perl tool you can download and run on your markdowned text files. Markdown is simple and intuitive.

Examples here: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/basics